# Wicket asynchronous job

Tags: ajax, wicket, wicket-1.5

I have a page on which I load more select lists with many values populated from database. Now from data base I cannot do much more to optimize that select I'm wondering if is possible to do something from wicket, something to populate that list asynchronous or something with ajax to load that selects asynchronous because my page is oppened very hard :|

```
<select>
<option1>Value1</option>
<option2>Value2</option>
<option1000>Value1000</option>
</select>
```

thank's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no paging dropdown or "endless scroll" component for Wicket natively.

But there is a component in jQuery under the Apache License:

http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

And there is a Wicket component:

https://github.com/ivaynberg/wicket-select2

As Wicket 6.x uses jQuery natively it should be a good fit.

Sebastian

Comment: Unfortunatley I use wicket 1.4 :( Shoul work in 1.4 version of wicket?

Comment: According to the readme: https://github.com/ivaynberg/wicket-select2/blob/master/README.md => No

Comment: However you might just download/read the component and could try to make it work with Wicket 1.4.